# Prefered style for multiple elements in JSON?

Tags: json

I am trying to represent a user's selection with a JSON object, and I am uncertain about the exact representation.

A user can select up to 4 unique elements from a list of items. The list of items will increase over time, while the choice of 4 elements is unlikely to ever change (but not impossible).

Is it better to store the selection as object with four properties or as array? Here is my rationale:

---

**As Properties**

```
"selection" : {
    "selection1" : "itemFoo",
    "selection2" : "itemBar",
    "selection3" : "itemBaz",
    "selection4" : null //<-- User does not need to select all 4 items
}
```

*Pros:*

- Does not allow more than 4 items selected by design

*Cons:*

- Makes it more difficult to check for uniqueness than in an array
- Makes extension more difficult than in an array

---

**As Array**

```
"selection" : [
    "itemFoo", "itemBar", "itemBaz"
]
```

*Pros:*

- Less overhead
- More intuitive representation of multiple items

*Cons:*

- Requires assertion to ensure that the array does not contain more than 4 elements

Comment: What do you mean by "Requires assertion if array has more than 4 items" ?

Comment: The requirement stated in the beginning is that users can select up to 4, but not more items. As such, when using an array, one needs to assert that the array contains 4 items maximum

Comment: Going with the first approach is an overkill. It's going to be harder to build the list especially if you allow to select / unselect items. The trade-of in asserting the number of items isn't that big, so I would go with the second approach.

Comment: @RobertD.Mogos I thought so too at first, but then considered that an array might be designed for an `1..n` scenario and not an `1..4`. But if you write an answer, I'd happily accept and upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with the first approach is an overkill. 
It's going to be harder to build the list especially if you allow to select / unselect items.

The trade-of in asserting the number of items isn't that big, so I would go with the second approach.

Based on the programming language that you use, you can enforce the desired size.